# R: Finding annualized average return in R

Tags: r

*Hi. I have an assignment where the following question is: Find the average annualized return for the data. The data I have consist of monthly returns from 1981-01 to 2019-12. I have tried for several hours to find a formula/code that can help me finding the average annualized return, but Im only finding information regarding other types of annualized returns. Do you guys have any suggestions?``

Comment: Could you `dput()` the data and copy + paste to your post?

Comment: Never done it before, but I can try to give a better explanation of the problem . I have imported data consisting of monthly arithmetic returns for the Apple Stock. The first task wants me to convert the returns to log returns, which was easy to do. The next task wants me to compute (for each year) the average return and the standard deviation. I dont understand how I am supposed to make R understand that it has to make a new column with average annualized return, for each year.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you tried already or which library you used, please see if below works for you:

```
> library(quantmod)
> getSymbols("AAPL", from = '2019-01-01', to = '2019-12-31')
[1] "AAPL"
> apple <- data.frame(AAPL)
> head(apple)
           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
2019-01-02   38.7225   39.7125  38.5575    39.4800   148158800      38.62910
2019-01-03   35.9950   36.4300  35.5000    35.5475   365248800      34.78135
2019-01-04   36.1325   37.1375  35.9500    37.0650   234428400      36.26614
2019-01-07   37.1750   37.2075  36.4750    36.9825   219111200      36.18543
2019-01-08   37.3900   37.9550  37.1300    37.6875   164101200      36.87523
2019-01-09   37.8225   38.6325  37.4075    38.3275   180396400      37.50143
> apple_adj <- apple['AAPL.Adjusted']
> head(apple_adj)
           AAPL.Adjusted
2019-01-02      38.62910
2019-01-03      34.78135
2019-01-04      36.26614
2019-01-07      36.18543
2019-01-08      36.87523
2019-01-09      37.50143
> apple_adj$apple_daily_return <- ROC(apple_adj$AAPL.Adjusted, type = 'discrete')
> head(apple_adj)
           AAPL.Adjusted apple_daily_return
2019-01-02      38.62910                 NA
2019-01-03      34.78135        -0.09960740
2019-01-04      36.26614         0.04268928
2019-01-07      36.18543        -0.00222563
2019-01-08      36.87523         0.01906292
2019-01-09      37.50143         0.01698173
```

You may calculate returns from here.

Answer (score 0):

what about this? (not validated)

```
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(data.table)
getSymbols("AAPL", from = '2010-01-01', to = '2019-12-31')
monthly <- to.monthly(AAPL, indexAt = "last", OHLC = FALSE)
monthly_returns <- Return.calculate(monthly, method = "log")
yearly_mean <- apply.yearly(monthly_returns, mean)
yearly_mean$Annu <- (yearly_mean$AAPL.Adjusted + 1)^12 - 1
```

Comment: Since I already had the monthly return, and have to deal with the data I already have, I tried to use your 2 last code lines to find yearly mean. I get the error message "Must be either xts-coercible or timebased". It sounds like I have to convert my data in to xts. Do you eventually know how?

Comment: would have been easier if you had shared some sample data with dput(). since i dont have data i can't solve directly your pb, but I would think as.xts(mydf) might work?

Answer (score 0):

The annualized average return are just the mean of the daily returns ie with a simple group_by year and summarise mean you can easily get the results

```
library(quantmod)
library(tidyverse)
getSymbols("AAPL", from = '1981-01-01', to = '2019-12-31',  periodicity = 'monthly')
apple <- data.frame( AAPL )

apple %>% rownames_to_column %>% mutate(Year = format(as.Date(rowname),'%Y'), monthly_returns=  lag( AAPL.Adjusted)/AAPL.Adjusted - 1 ) %>% group_by(Year) %>% summarise(annual = mean(monthly_returns, na.rm=T))
# A tibble: 39 x 2
   Year    annual
   <chr>    <dbl>
 1 1981   0.0383 
 2 1982  -0.0131 
 3 1983   0.0430 
 4 1984  -0.0104 
 5 1985   0.0295 
 6 1986  -0.0448 
 7 1987  -0.0403 
 8 1988   0.00526
 9 1989   0.0164 
10 1990  -0.0101 
# … with 29 more rows
```

Comment: I understand your example. But in this case I have already been given the monthly returns from an imported dataset. I dont quite understand how to make R understand that is has to calculate the average annual returns for each year, and make a column.

Comment: @123321 simply change daily to monthly